# Backup: /proc /sys

Tags: backup, proc

Is it possible to take a backup of `/proc` ?

Almost all the backup utility suggests to avoid the `/proc, /sys, /tmp` directories. Former two are dynamic directories but I guess, having backup of these two directories will help to track down the issue without looking at problematic machine.

Problematic machine can take the backup of these two directories and send to someone who can dig for problems from system point of view.

Comment: `/proc/kcore` is going to give you some trouble ;-). You'll also find that lots of backup tools don't appreciate files changing while they're backing them up, which tends to happen with `/proc` and `/sys`...

Comment: Well, for that, can we have something like `cd /proc; tar cvf proc.tar * --exclude=kcore` ?

Comment: There are also many non-readable files, you should ignore them. BTW many util-linux programs, like ```lscpu``` have an option like ```--sysroot``` to work on such /sys copy (one point more for the usefulness of such copy).